# Is it possible to use a binary search of git repos to locate a bug?

Tags: git, accessibility, xorg

Somewhere between xorg 7.6 and 7.7, the keyboard accessibility features were degraded to the point where any distro running 7.7 is effectively unusable to me.

Is there a tool that assists developers in performing a binary search of commits to help locate a bug?

For example, the pivot would initially be the middle commit: apply git updates, build, test.  If the feature still works, choose a pivot 3/4 of the way; if not, 1/4.

...and so on until you find the update that caused the degradation.

I would love to upgrade to Wheezy, but the broken keyboard accessibility is a major impediment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. Google it or use the command line to see how it works:

```
man git-bisect
```